# Strange behaviour of whiptail

Tags: bash, iptables, whiptail

My code:

```
read -ra var <<<$(sed -ne's/^ *:\([[:upper:]]*\).*/\1/p' /etc/sysconfig/iptables)
chains=$(whiptail --title "Add rule" --menu "chains" 16 78 5 "${var[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

I would like to have all avaliable iptables chains in whiptail menu but when I run my script I got this:

[image: screenshot with empty Add rule window]

But when I add to whiptail syntax `--ok-button` I got this:

```
chains=$(whiptail --title "Add rule" --menu "chains" 16 78 5 --ok-button "${var[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

[image: screenshot with output forward selection]

I know I should write some choice after --ok-button (e.g. Ok) but when I run this script I got what is shown in the first image.

I added beyond `--menu` tag `--notags` and I still got what is shown in the first image.

If I delete space:

```
chains=$(whiptail --title "Add rule" --menu "chains" 16 78 5 --ok-button Ok"${var[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

I got this:

[image: screenshot with output selection]

Well I want to add a tag `--notags` to show just items in array `var`

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: It would be easier to follow if you showed the complete script at each point.  The pictures are large and a distraction.

Comment: @thomasdickey done

Answer (score 2):

The `--notags` and `--ok-button` options should go *before* the `--menu` option.  Those modify the behavior of the *menu* widget.

The documentation for *whiptail* needs some work.  You might find the manual page for [dialog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html) helpful: I see from `strings /usr/bin/whiptail` that *whiptail* has a `--notags` option, but it is not described in [*whiptail*'s](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/whiptail.1.html) manual page.  In dialog:

```
   --no-tags
          Some  widgets  (checklist, inputmenu, radiolist, menu) display a
          list with two columns (a "tag" and "description").  The  tag  is
          useful  for scripting, but may not help the user.  The --no-tags
          option (from Xdialog) may be used to suppress the column of tags
          from  the  display.  Unlike the --no-items option, this does not
          affect the data which is read from the script
```

*dialog* maps `--notags` to `-no-tags` (*Xdialog* implemented the feature first, using the latter name).